# SQL Query, subquery minus subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Ok, so Ive been trying to get this query working for hours now, but nothing I seem to do will get me the results I am after.

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ps.cost), 0) AS ps_total
FROM Customers c
    LEFT JOIN ProductSales ps ON c.customer_ID = ps.customer_ID
GROUP BY c.sex;

SELECT COALESCE(SUM(hc.cost), 0) AS hc_total
FROM Customers c
    LEFT JOIN HairCuts hc ON c.customer_ID = hc.customer_ID
GROUP BY c.sex;
```

So the above two queries work fine. Each one finds the total spent on either products or hair cuts and groups by gener thus giving me the total spent on cuts and products for males and females individually.However somehow I need to combine these in such a way that I can display the gender(s) that spent more on products than on haircuts.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated.

P.S hopefully the question is clear enough. If not Ill try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way you can join your both query results as

```
SELECT  t1.sex,
COALESCE(t1.ps_total - t2.hc_total,0)  AS `difference`
FROM 
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ps.cost), 0) AS ps_total ,c.sex
FROM Customers c
    LEFT JOIN ProductSales ps ON c.customer_ID = ps.customer_ID
GROUP BY c.sex) t1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(hc.cost), 0) AS hc_total ,c.sex
FROM Customers c
    LEFT JOIN HairCuts hc ON c.customer_ID = hc.customer_ID
GROUP BY c.sex) t2
USING(sex)
HAVING difference > 0
```

**Edit from comments**

I have used a short syntax for `ON()` clause like `USING(sex)` = `ON(t1.sex=t2.sex)` if you have a same name for a column in both tables you can use `USING()` if you have different then you need to use `ON()` syntax

Like

> Table1 column(category_id primary key,...)
>
> Table2 column(category_id foreign key,...)

Then you can easily use `USING()`

```
SELECT * FROM
Table1 
JOIN Table2 
USING(category_id )
```

But if you have different name for association then you need to use `ON()` clause

Comment: This is so close. Except instead of just displaying the difference, which this does. I need it to display the gender and only if the difference is greater than 1. IE display male if males bought more products than cuts AND/OR display female if females bought more products than cuts. Does that make sense?

Comment: @user3596312 see my updated answer,is this you need ?

Comment: Aye that's what I need, except that you have a having clause without a group by clause. I just added, group by sex before it. Also Isnt it better to have > 0; Not 1? Just wondering.

Comment: Also, can you explain to me how the using clause down there us working. I don't really understand it.

Comment: @user3596312 `HAVING` is not restricted to filter only the results from aggregate functions and also as from your previous comment you ask for >1 so i added > 1 :) but i guess >0 would be sufficient

Comment: @user3596312 for `USING()` you can see my updated answer

Comment: Ahh sorry, that was a typo on my part, wasn't thinking. And, fair enough its just that my DBMS had an error with having and no group by before it. Anyway, I think Ive got it sorted now. Thanks for your assistance.